# How to do SUM over month columns in past year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have following columns from Jan to Dec:

```
Year - Jan - Feb - Mar - (etc.) - Dec
----   ---   ---   ---            ---
2015   25    32    102            12
2016   30    40    50             60
```

How to effectively do SUM over past year? 
Let's say from GETDATE(), If today is 18.07.2017, I want SUM from 18.07.2016 (from july 2016 till july 2017).

I have no idea how to do it effectively.

Comment: But you do not have day level granular data here, hence you can find month level sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot the data and then do the calculation:

```
select sum(val)
from t cross apply
     (values (t.year, t.Jan, 1),
             (t.year, t.Feb, 2),
             . . .
     ) v(yyyy, val, mon)
where yyyy * 100 + mon >= (year(getdate()) - 1) * 100 + month(getdate());
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without cross apply?

Comment: @JúliusMarko . . . Probably, but this results in the simplest query.

Comment: because we have internal compiler, and that results to some errors, but it is doing ok in computation. So If you are able to give solution without cross apply, I would be grateful. I have no idea doing it without cross apply.

Comment: @JúliusMarko . . . I would suggest that you ask another question and tag it with the compiler that you are really using.  `apply` has been part of SQL Server for a long, long time.